# ADC conversion timing

Tags: microcontroller, adc, sample-and-hold

Why the conversion time of an ADC is calculated as: number of bits in resolution+number of programmed sample clocks+2/(ADC clock frequency) ?  As far as I know for the successive approximation A/D converter, a clock cycle is the time it takes for a bit so number of bits in resolution would give us n cycles, so why this number is added to 2 and the whole thing is divided to the clock frequency? The microcontroller is HCS 12 and uses successive approximation A/D converter

Comment: You should try looking at some really complex SPI ADCs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial 2 clocks are to sample the input signal onto a capacitor.

Then there is a programmable time (The programmed sample clocks) where the sample is transferred to the capacitors that form the A/D.

Lastly the successive approximation algorithm then takes one clock per bit as you say.

[image: Total conversion time]

The division by the clock frequency is to convert the result to time (in us if you use the frequency in MHz) rather than a number of clocks.

The following application note has the details: [AN2428](http://cache.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/app_note/AN2428.pdf)

Comment: I thought "number of programmed sample clocks" accounted for the sampling time. Or is that just an adjustable amount on top of a fixed base of two clocks for sampling?

Comment: Can you give a link to the datasheet?

Comment: It is a book: hsc12/9s12 an introduction to software and hardware interfacing